Add a new column based on the complement of column data in a table
I have this code to replace the data of each row in a specific function and display a new column showing the values ​​of the function
RS = 1 - (1 - Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2]) (1 - 
      Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 3]);
(data = Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]) // MatrixForm; LLR = {Block[{Subscript}, 
   Do[Subscript[x, j] = Transpose[data][[j]], {j, 3}]; RS]};
(table = Prepend[
    Transpose@Join[{Range@Length@data}, Transpose@data, LLR], 
    Flatten[{"order", Subscript["x", #] & /@ Range[3], "H"}]]) // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &


I am looking for taking the complement of each column separately ($1-x_1$,$1-x_2$,$1-x_3$) and substituting the complement with the rest of the columns and displaying the result of the function in another columns ($H1,H2,H3$).
In other words, the complement of the first column ($1-x_1$) with the second ($x_2$ and third ($x_3$) columns gives $H1$,  ($1-x_2$) with  ($x_1$ and  ($x_3$)  gives $H2$, ($1-x_3$) with  ($x_1$ and  ($x_2$)  gives $H3$
My attempts gave accurate results but the code seems to be useless in more general cases. When the number of variables increases.
RS = 1 - (1 - Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2]) (1 - 
      Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 3]);
RS1 = 1 - (1 - Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2]) (1 - 
       Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 3]) /. 
   Subscript[x, 1] -> (1 - Subscript[x, 1]) ;
RS2 = 1 - (1 - Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2]) (1 - 
       Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 3]) /. 
   Subscript[x, 2] -> (1 - Subscript[x, 2]) ;
RS3 = 1 - (1 - Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2]) (1 - 
       Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 3]) /. 
   Subscript[x, 3] -> (1 - Subscript[x, 3]) ;
(data = Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]) // MatrixForm; LLR = {Block[{Subscript}, 
   Do[Subscript[x, j] = Transpose[data][[j]], {j, 3}]; RS]};
LLR1 = {Block[{Subscript}, 
    Do[Subscript[x, j] = Transpose[data][[j]], {j, 3}]; RS1]};
LLR2 = {Block[{Subscript}, 
    Do[Subscript[x, j] = Transpose[data][[j]], {j, 3}]; RS2]};
LLR3 = {Block[{Subscript}, 
    Do[Subscript[x, j] = Transpose[data][[j]], {j, 3}]; RS3]};
(table = Prepend[
    Transpose@
     Join[{Range@Length@data}, Transpose@data, LLR, LLR1, LLR2, LLR3],
     Flatten[{"order", Subscript["x", #] & /@ Range[3], "H", "H1", 
      "H2", "H3"}]]) // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &


I have put a condition on the function and duplicated the code... but this seems to be useless in general.
I am looking for better dynamics for the code in more general cases.
Thanks a lot for the help

So, you want something that generalizes when you add an x4 (and then x5, etc)? So your core data structure would be Tuples[{0, 1}, n] where you started with n = 3 and you want to expand to n > 3, is that right?

@lericr Yes exactly. For example: in the case I am working on, the table is in the form: Tuples[{0, 1}, 10] and the variables are $x_1,x_2,...,x_{10}$

Okay, help me understand how the RS should be generated. For the n = 3 case, we took all pairs that included x1 (so we excluded the term that would have used x2 x3). So, for n = 4 will we take the terms built from x1 x2, x1 x3, and x1 x4? That's half of the possible 6 ways to pair up the terms. Or is it a more complicated rule?

@lericr Of course, the function changes as the number of variables increases. The function is an input. There is no basic formula for it. For example, n=4, RS=1-(1-x1 x2)(1-x3 x4) and for n=5, RS=1-(1-x1)(1-x2)(1-x4)(1-x3 x5). Can the function be considered an input and may change?

Sure. That actually makes it kind of easier.

@lericr You can assume any first-degree function with the number of variables you need. So as an input. If you change it, it will not affect the operation of the code.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

And just to be completely clear, the extended columns (H1, H2, etc) are derived by just replacing each xN with (1-xN) in whatever formula we're given, right?

@lericr Yes, this is what I am looking for.

Let's build this up bit by bit. At each step, there are probably several alternate ways to do it, so you might want to experiment to figure out exactly what you want.
First, we need a representation for each "function template". I'm assuming that there's one for each "dimension", but you may need to expand this if you want to play around with different functions for each "dimension".
RS[3] = Function[, 1 - (1 - #1 #2) (1 - #1 #3)];
RS[4] = Function[, 1 - (1 - #1 #2) (1 - #3 #4)];
RS[5] = Function[, 1 - (1 - #1) (1 - #2) (1 - #4) (1 - #3 #5)];

Now let's come up with a general way to make the variable names. This is mostly for the header in the display, but it'll also be nice to demonstrate things.
MakeVariables[n_] := Indexed[\[FormalX], {#}] & /@ Range[n]

So,
MakeVariables[3]
(* {Indexed[\[FormalX], {1}], Indexed[\[FormalX], {2}], Indexed[\[FormalX], {3}]} *)

I'm using FormalX to avoid collisions and also just to be clear that these are just dummy variables for now. I'm also using Indexed instead of Subscript because it will give us nice behavior if we want to replace FormalX with an array. But of course, you could substitute Subscript if you really want.
Just to demonstrate what we have so far:
RS[3] @@ MakeVariables[3]
(* 1 - (1 - Indexed[\[FormalX], {1}] Indexed[\[FormalX], {2}]) (1 - Indexed[\[FormalX], {1}] Indexed[\[FormalX], {3}]) *)

Now let's create a helper function to take the complement of a variable.
ComplementFn = Function[, 1 - #]

This is kind of overkill, but it'll keep things tidy.
Now, we want to apply our template function (RS[3] for now) to a list of inputs, but we'll go ahead and do all of the complements first. This will create all the argument lists that you want.
argLists = Through[(MapAt[ComplementFn, {{#}}] & /@ Subsets[Range[3], 1])[MakeVariables[3]]]

(*
    {{Indexed[\[FormalX], {1}], Indexed[\[FormalX], {2}], Indexed[\[FormalX], {3}]}, 
     {1 - Indexed[\[FormalX], {1}], Indexed[\[FormalX], {2}], Indexed[\[FormalX], {3}]}, 
     {Indexed[\[FormalX], {1}], 1 - Indexed[\[FormalX], {2}], Indexed[\[FormalX], {3}]}, 
     {Indexed[\[FormalX], {1}], Indexed[\[FormalX], {2}], 1 - Indexed[\[FormalX], {3}]}}
*)

That's using some abstract functionality, so if it's not clear how it works, break it apart into sub-expressions and play with it. Anyway, now we have 4 argument lists that we can apply our function to.
RS[3] @@@ argLists


Okay, but we actually want to apply it to the binary tuples. So let's use our functions on the tuples.
concreteArgLists = Through[(MapAt[ComplementFn, {{#}}] & /@ Subsets[Range[3], 1])[Transpose[Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]]]]


And now let's apply our template function:
RS[3] @@@ concreteArgLists
(* {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}} *)

That's your 4 columns H, H1, H2, H3.
To get the five columns for the 4 dimensional case:
RS[4] @@@ Through[(MapAt[ComplementFn, {{#}}] & /@ Subsets[Range[4], 1])[Transpose[Tuples[{0, 1}, 4]]]]


For display, you could do something like this:
TableForm[
  Transpose[Join[Transpose[Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]], RS[3] @@@ concreteArgLists]],
  TableHeadings -> {Range[8], Flatten[{MakeVariables[3], "H", "H1", "H2", "H3"}]}]


That could be wrapped up in its own function, and you could use Grid if you want.

Accurate answer. Thank you very much. It helped me a lot.
